# Add date (24 format) to file name?

Tags: powershell

This line dose a fine job of renaming my file but it only use the hours 00-12 and not 13-24. After 12 it begins with 01. Sins it does not append AM or PM you cant know bu just looking at the file name when it was created. I would like it to use 24h format.

```
dir C:\script\logged_in_users-.csv | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName+(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh)+$_.Extension}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your format string, use `HH` instead of `hh`, to output hours in 24-hour format.

Comment: Also, I'd say a format string makes that more readable: `Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}{1:yyyy-MM-dd-HH}{2}' -f $_.BaseName,(Get-Date),$_.Extension }`

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. Just change to HH in my old code did not work. Now everything works fine. Ugly code for the most part but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Swap `hh` for `HH` for 24-hour clock timestamp.

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx